# If $\operatorname{det}[a_{ij}] \neq 0$, then $\operatorname{det}[a_{ij}^{-1}] \neq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let's consider a $n \times n$ matrix $A := [a_{ij}]$ over a field $F$, where each $a_{ij}$ are nonzero so that each has an inverse $a_{ij}^{-1}$ in $F$.

My question is,

if the determinant of $A$, $\operatorname{det}[a_{ij}]$, is nonzero, then  $\operatorname{det}[a_{ij}^{-1}] \neq 0$ ?

If $n=2$, then we may show the claim. Then how about $n \ge 3$ ?

Using the determinant formula ${\displaystyle \det(A)=\sum _{\sigma \in S_{n}}\left(\operatorname {sgn}(\sigma )\prod _{i=1}^{n}a_{i,\sigma _{i}}\right)}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1/2 & 1/3 \\
1/2 & 1/3 & 1/4 \\
1/3 & 1/4 & 1/5
 \end{array} \right)
$$
is invertible, hence $\det(A) \not=0$,  whereas
$$
B=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 4 \\
3 & 4 & 5
 \end{array} \right)
$$
has $\det(B)=0$.

Comment: In fact, $\det(A)=\frac{1}{2160}$.

Comment: O.K. Thank you~

Comment: Matrix $B$ is singular because column $3$ is just twice column $2$ minus column $1$ (and likewise for the rows).